# How can I display an image from an array of pixels' values in java?

Tags: java, image

I intended to display a 28x28 pixels image inside the window. The pixels have "0" value, so I expected it to display a window with a black square of 28x28. But no image is displayed instead. Maybe array's data (I don't know for sure if pixel values must be an int in range from 0 to 255) must be other in order to display the image. Thanks!

public class ASD {

```
public static Image getImageFromArray(int[] pixels, int width, int height) {
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    WritableRaster raster = (WritableRaster) image.getData();
    System.out.println(pixels.length + " " + width + " " + height);
    raster.setPixels(0,0,width,height,pixels);
    return image;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    JFrame jf = new JFrame();
    JLabel jl = new JLabel();

    int[] arrayimage = new int[784];
    for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++)
    {   for (int j = 0; j < 28; j++)
            arrayimage[i*28+j] = 0;
    }
    ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(getImageFromArray(arrayimage,28,28));
    jl.setIcon(ii);
    jf.add(jl);
    jf.pack();
    jf.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`image.getData()` returns a *copy* of the raster.
Perhaps if you call `image.setData(raster)` after you modify the raster you will see results.

Also, setPixels should be given an array large enough to fill all the bands (A, R, G, B) of the raster.  I had gotten an array index out of bounds exception until I increased the size of pixels to be 28*28*4.

For TYPE_INT_RGB, the following should produce a white image:

```
public class ASD
{
  public static Image getImageFromArray(int[] pixels, int width, int height)
  {
    BufferedImage image =
        new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    WritableRaster raster = (WritableRaster) image.getData();
    raster.setPixels(0, 0, width, height, pixels);
    image.setData(raster);
    return image;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    JFrame jf = new JFrame();
    JLabel jl = new JLabel();

    //3 bands in TYPE_INT_RGB
    int NUM_BANDS = 3;
    int[] arrayimage = new int[28 * 28 * NUM_BANDS];

    for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < 28; j++) {
        for (int band = 0; band < NUM_BANDS; band++)
          arrayimage[((i * 28) + j)*NUM_BANDS + band] = 255;
      }
    }
    ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(getImageFromArray(arrayimage, 28, 28));
    jl.setIcon(ii);
    jf.add(jl);
    jf.pack();
    jf.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: I've changed: 1) array size to 28*28*3(all 0 values), 2)TYPE_INT_ARGB  to TYPE_INT_RGB, 3) and called image.setData(raster) after setPixels. But still no image is displayed.

Comment: @Alexander, above is your code changed to produce a white image.  It works for me anyway... Are you getting a JFrame, or is your program terminating without any effect?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know it this is the problem, but you are using 
[TYPE_INT_ARGB](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#TYPE_INT_ARGB). This includes an Alpha channel ([opacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space)) in the packed integer, a value of 0 means fully transparent.

Another one (read the [docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getData%28%29)!):

```
BufferedImage.getData() :  The Raster returned is a copy of the image data is not updated if the image is changed.
```

You must call setData() to place the new pixels inside the image, I think.

Comment: Ok, I changed it to TYPE_INT_RGB; but the problem persists. And also the image is not displayed regardless of array values, be it 0 or any other value. Thanks.

Comment: Must the array be of the size = width*height*3, for every channel; where 0..width*height contains the values of red, width*height+1..2*width*height the values of green and 2*width*height+1..width*height*3 the values of blue? Thanks.

Comment: `TYPE_INT_RGB` packs the three samples (one for each pixel) that compose a pixel in a single integer.