# how to convert image from coordinate x,y values in java?

Tags: java

In my project we need spot the difference among a set of images,so at first i tried it for three images and I have written code to differentiate between three images based on RGB values.I have stored coordinate values from this values i need to get a image.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
class spe
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    throws IOException
    {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int q=0;
            File file1 = new File("filename.txt");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file1.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        File file= new File("2010.png");
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
        int width = image.getWidth(null);
            int height = image.getHeight(null);
        int[][] clr=  new int[width][height]; 
        File files= new File("2011.png");
            BufferedImage images = ImageIO.read(files);
        int widthe = images.getWidth(null);
            int heighte = images.getHeight(null);
        File file2=new File("2009.png");
        BufferedImage image2=ImageIO.read(file2);
        int wid=image2.getWidth(null);
        int heig=image2.getHeight(null);
        int[][] colo=new int[wid][heig];
        int[][] clre=  new int[widthe][heighte]; 
        int smw=0;
        int smh=0;
        int p=0;
        //  bw.write("hai");
            //CALUCLATING THE SMALLEST VALUE AMONG WIDTH AND HEIGHT
            if(width>widthe)
            { 
                smw =widthe;
            }
            else 
            {
                smw=width;
            }
            if(height>heighte)
            {
                smh=heighte;
            }
            else 
            {
                smh=height;
            }
            //CHECKING NUMBER OF PIXELS SIMILARITY
            for(int a=0;a<smw;a++)
            {
                for(int b=0;b<smh;b++)
                {
                    clre[a][b]=images.getRGB(a,b);
                    clr[a][b]=image.getRGB(a,b);
                    colo[a][b]=image2.getRGB(a,b);
                    if(clr[a][b]==clre[a][b] && colo[a][b]==clre[a][b]) 
                    {
                        p=p+1;
                        bw.write("\t");
                         bw.write(Integer.toString(a));
                        bw.write("\t");
                         bw.write(Integer.toString(b)); 
                        bw.write("\n");
                        System.out.println(a+"\t"+b);
                    }
                    else
                        q=q+1;
                }
            }

    float w,h=0;
    if(width>widthe) 
    {
        w=width;
    }
    else 
    {
        w=widthe;
    }
    if(height>heighte)
    { 
        h = height;
    }
    else
    {
        h = heighte;
    }
    float s = (smw*smh);
    //CALUCLATING PERCENTAGE
    float x =(100*p)/s;

    System.out.println("THE PERCENTAGE SIMILARITY IS APPROXIMATELY ="+x+"%");
    long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("TIME TAKEN IS ="+(stop-start));
    System.out.println("NO OF PIXEL GETS VARIED:="+q);
    System.out.println("NO OF PIXEL GETS MATCHED:="+p);
  }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157020/how-can-i-display-an-image-from-an-array-of-pixels-values-in-java?rq=1 maybe