# Exception in deciding width and height of the Image

Tags: java, image

I was trying to make an image from my default array of pixels. But Exception occurs everytime i increase width and height of an image.
I think that the no. of pixels must be equal to width and height of the image.
Any Suggestion...

[image]

```
  try{
     BufferedImage writeImage=new BufferedImage(512,512,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
     File outputfile = new File("C://Users//GamingPC//Desktop//out11.png");
     WritableRaster raster = (WritableRaster)writeImage.getData();
     raster.setPixels(0, 0,temp , temp, pixel);
     writeImage.setData(raster);
     ImageIO.write(writeImage, "png", outputfile);

     }
     catch (IOException ex) {}
```

Comment: You must have sufficient data in your pixel array to fill the BufferedImage. In your case that is 512 * 512 * 4 elements.

Comment: Have you seen [this SO response](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6157350/758831) - notably "Also, setPixels should be given an array large enough to fill all the bands (A, R, G, B) of the raster. I had gotten an array index out of bounds exception until I increased the size of pixels to be 28*28*4.".

Comment: I have an array of 10^6 pixels Please suggest me the parameters to be passed in the function @AlexanderBrevig

Comment: You're 48576 entries short then, I think that'll fix it

Comment: for 10^6 I think I have to pass 500 and 500 as arguments but it is still giving me the same error @AlexanderBrevig